# Can I to pass custom param/prop from config.js to breadcrumbs? [Pro Antd React]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I have **pro antd application**.

I have a problem: I want my breadcrumb item to have different name from **name** in config.

I want to pass the param of the breadcrumb label for current route in config.js

How can I do it?

In **itemRender** methos param *route* doesn't have custom props, which I pass to config.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to antd pro docs

> Breadcrumbs are implemented by PageHeaderWrapper, Layout will be
> rendered according to breadcrumb generated by MenuData and rendered by
> PageHeaderWrapper. PageHeaderWrapper is packaged into Ant Design's
> PageHeader, and the api is identical.

The way I changed breadcrumb label, is set value in `locale` then localization folder then `menu.js`. then used that same name for routing in config.
For example, let say I want to set breadcrumb for `settings/roles` to be `My Setting/My Role`
Then in config.js file ->

```
{
    name: 'settings',
    path: '/setting',
    routes:[
    {
       name: 'roles',
       path: '/setting/roles',
       component: './Setting/Roles',
    },
}
```

Then in `src` > `locales` > `en-US` > `menu.js`

```
'menu.settings' : "My Setting",
'menu.settings.roles' : "My Role",
```

Then I will get the breadcrumb `My Setting/My Role`
Here I had to go to `en-US` > `menu.js` because in `config.js` I have set

```
locale: {
    default: 'en-US',
}
```

To change the divider `"/"` between names, go to `BasicLayout.jsx`, find `itemRender`, there you will find

```
<Link to={paths.join('/')}>{route.breadcrumbName}</Link>
```

this line is the one that displays in breadcrumb. From `menu.js`, we are setting the `route.breadcrumbName`